# In android How to make the service runnable thread to wait for the activity to get finished

Tags: android, service, runnable

From service which is running indefinitely at the background, there i have created a runnable thread for network operation and trying to start the activity from the service, The activity starts and function smoothly but of course the service keep on running.. (after the activity comes to focus.). I want to make my service to resume back its following code after the activity finishes its work or calls ondestroy(). How this can be achieved. ?

Comment: What if you do nothing after starting your activity and in your activity's ondestroy call startService again passing some flag so you server sees it and does whatever is needed?

Comment: ya i did thought about it.. but performance wise its not a best solution.

Comment: Why do you think so? Seems to be the opposite - you do nothing the whole time your activity stays up. Maybe you should split your service in two..

Comment: Seems like i am totally tired to think .. Thanks Alex. Let me try it once

Comment: Maybe you could make use of ExecutorService and FutureTask so you wait for completion

Comment: yaa I have to see your other solution.. since i can't stop the service since in my service, I am running a thread which is doing network task